# Clarification needed about using relative file paths with the Cache API - comparability within caches.match()

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, offline, directory-structure

Assume that a `service-worker.js` is ready to offer offline browsing ability thanks to the following code,

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith( caches.match(event.request).then( cachedResponse => {   return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);   } )  );
});
```

And let's say we have cached some assets where the files are listed relative to the root directory,

```
const cacheAssets = await caches.open('necessary-files-v1');
const listOfFiles = [
    "/somefolder/somepage.html",
    "/somefolder/somevisual.jpg",
    "/somefolder/someaudio.mp3"
];
await cacheAssets.addAll(listOfFiles);
```

Now compare the offline case for the following two (obviously they both work fine when online),

**Scenario 1**: `somepage.html` contains `<img src="somevisual.jpg">`

**Scenario 2**: `somepage.html` contains `<img src="/somefolder/somevisual.jpg">`

Given the fact that the string to string comparison `("somevisual.jpg" == "/somefolder/somevisual.jpg")` will return `false` should we always and always adopt **Scenario 2** when building our html files with the hope of offline compatibility? Or is there a case or some method that offers us developers some nice-to-have flexibility?

Comment: Looks like this question is somewhat related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205580/can-the-service-worker-access-browser-cache?rq=1

Comment: In case you want to know about the benefits of using service workers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916074/why-use-a-service-worker-for-caching-when-browser-cache-handles-the-caching

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to make a string comparison; and I don't see that happening in your code. I believe the nice-to-have flexibility that you're looking for should be built in to the browser APIs (`cache.addAll` and `fetch`) and [Request object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request); string URLs can be converted into `Request` objects for comparison.

For example, `cache.addAll` invokes the `Request` constructor [on each of the strings you pass in](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#cache-addAll), and you're passing in a `Request` to `caches.match` (as `event.request`). So the actual [matching algorithm](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#request-matches-cached-item) should be comparing something more like `Request("/somefolder/somevisual.jpg")` to `Request("somevisual.jpg")` (from `event.request` in the fetch event) rather than a string comparison like `("somevisual.jpg" == "/somefolder/somevisual.jpg")`. I would think the former should generally account for the different paths, though I imagine there could still be edge cases to consider like query parameters.

Does this not work when you test?

As an aside, I see you aren't opening the cache, as in [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/match), which may be causing you troubles (I'm not sure though, I haven't used these API's in years).